# What happens to articles in phrases "a bit <adjective> <noun>"?

Tags: articles, determiners

Consider the phrase "I'm doing this for a bit different reason."

The grouping here is "((a bit) different) reason" and not "a ((bit different) reason)", so the noun "reason" lacks an article.

Does "a bit different" itself act as a determiner here? Or is the article implicit and simply omitted to avoid repetition?

Comment: That's not right, it should be something like *a bit of a different reason*. *Of a* can be slurred, though.

Comment: @Cerberus: interesting. What's the grammatical role of "of a" here?

Comment: There is *a different reason*, and we take *a bit of* it. It is a noun phrase (*a bit*) modified by another noun phrase (*a different reason*). *That is a bit different* is another construction: there *a bit* modifies the adjective *different* directly, and there is no noun phrase. You can't easily combine the two, so the slightly odd *a bit of a* ensues. *A bit of a different reason* may sound slightly like *a bit different reason* in quick or sloppy speech.

Comment: Here you can see your *a bit different _NOUN_* is not used in print, whereas *a bit of a different* is. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bit+different+_NOUN_%2Cbit+of+a+different&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbit%20of%20a%20different%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Cerberus ok, I'm convinced that "of a" is the correct form. But interpreting "a bit of a ..." here as "a bit of something" sounds really odd. (Also, care to put this as an answer?)

Comment: Yes it is odd, but it is what I would call an explicative or defining genitive: you characterise the different reason as "a bit", as a small thing. It is akin to *he is a bear of a man*; that is not about a man possessing a bear, but about a bear that *is* a man. [Possessive constructions signifying semantic equation: term? distribution? explanation?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/possessive-constructions-signifying-semantic-equation-term-distribution-expla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your construction is not correct: it should be something like *a bit of a different reason*. You can see that *a bit different [noun]* is not [used in print](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bit%20different%20_NOUN_,bit%20of%20a%20different&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,bit%20of%20a%20different;,c0), whereas *a bit of a different* is.

There is a different reason, and we take a bit of it. It is a noun phrase (*a bit*) modified by another noun phrase (*a different reason*). *That is a bit different* is another construction: there *a bit* modifies the adjective *different* directly, and there is no noun phrase. You can't easily combine the two, so the slightly odd *a bit of a* ensues. *A bit of a different reason* may sound slightly like *a bit different reason* in quick or sloppy speech.

The construction is odd, but it is what I would call an **explicative or defining genitive**: you characterise the different reason as "a bit", as a small thing. It is akin to *he is a bear of a man*; that is not about a man possessing a bear, but about a bear that *is* a man.

See also this question on *Linguistics*: [possessive constructions signifying semantic equation: term? distribution? explanation?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/possessive-constructions-signifying-semantic-equation-term-distribution-expla)

Answer (score 0):

The full phrase **[a bit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/a-bit)** means

> Somewhat; to some extent

Derived from the noun, *bit*, the indefintie article *a* is part of the full phrase and is used in the axample adverbially to modify *different*. The sentence could have been constructed

> I'm doing this for a *somewhat* different reason.

In the alternative construction, the indefinite article that modifies *reason* is present. But directly substituting *a bit* for *somewhat* would result in

> I'm doing this for a *a bit* different reason.

Obviously unacceptable. We omit the second *a* to avoid clumsiness.